# Disable particular Node in CANoe using CAPL

Tags: capl, canoe

I am trying to disable a particular message of a node from sending default values available in dbc file, and through capl i need to transmit new(dummy) values.
I found the function ILNodeControlStop(), which blocks the node completely, but i want to block only one message and not block the entire node.

How to disable an ECU node from sending a message from IL?

Comment: Please can you upgrade your question with some more information? You can get some guidelines in [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
ILDisableMsg(<messageName>);
```

to disable the message and

```
ILEnableMsg(<messageName>);
```

to enable it again.

All this assuming, that you are using the CANoe interaction layer.